# Pictures keep going to the top left.(Actionscript 3)

Tags: image, actionscript-3

So my project was to make two gallery pages. I called them "gallery1" and "gallery2".The gallery pages each have 5 thumbnails that act like buttons so when you click on em, it opens an swf of the picture. Now the problem is, it always opens on the top left, i want them to be in the middle of the page. This is the code for gallery1. Gallery 2 is the samething but with different pics. b1-b5 are the thumbnails.Please help.

```
var swfRequest1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("image1.swf");
    var swfRequest2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("image2.swf");
    var swfRequest3:URLRequest = new URLRequest("image3.swf");
    var swfRequest4:URLRequest = new URLRequest("image4.swf");
    var swfRequest5:URLRequest = new URLRequest("image5.swf");

    var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();



function opengal(evt:MouseEvent):void





{   
        var pTarget:String = evt.currentTarget.name;

    if(pTarget == "b1")
    {
        swfLoader.load(swfRequest1);
        addChild(swfLoader);
    }
    else if(pTarget == "b2")
    {
        swfLoader.load(swfRequest2);
        addChild(swfLoader);
    }
    else if(pTarget == "b3")
    {
        swfLoader.load(swfRequest3);
        addChild(swfLoader);
    }
    else if (pTarget == "b4")
    {
        swfLoader.load(swfRequest4);
        addChild(swfLoader);
    }
    else if(pTarget == "b5")
    {
        swfLoader.load(swfRequest5);
        addChild(swfLoader);
    }
};


b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, opengal);
b2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, opengal);
b3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, opengal);
b4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, opengal);
b5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, opengal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set your loaded content in the middle of your stage, you can do like this :

```
// store files path into an array
var files:Array = ['image01.swf', 'image02.swf', 'image03.swf', 'image04.swf', 'image05.swf'];

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    // use loader.contentLoaderInfo to listen to Event.INIT
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.INIT, function(e:Event):void {
            // center our loader
            loader.x = (stage.stageWidth - loader.width)/2;
            loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - loader.height)/2;           
        })
    addChild(loader);                     

function opengal(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    // here the pTarget should be between 0 and 4 as an array index
    var pTarget:int = Number((evt.currentTarget.name).substr(-1, 1)) - 1;
    loader.load(new URLRequest(files[pTarget]));

};

...
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to position your `swfLoader` in the middle of the screen.

You can do this with this code:

```
swfLoader.x = (swfLoader.width - stage.stageWidth)/2; // and the y axis in a  similar way
```

The required width and height properties can be retrieved when the contentLoaderInfo dispatches an Event.INIT.

Comment: Hmm how would i do that?